# Exclude this workbook from a loop that open all folder

Tags: excel, vba

i have an issue on this . I have a macro that let me select the folder i want and then i have a loop on it which opens all excel files in it 
i want to exclude this workbook (the one containing the macro) so my idea was to exclude from the name or from the type (xlsm). 
any idea on the method to apply to solve it ? I thougt to use <> with a condition but i dont really know where and how to place it .

Here's the code 
Thanks for your help

```
  Sub macro3()
    Dim fso As Object, Dossier As Object, NomDossier, feuille As Worksheet
    Dim pvtTable As Object



    Dim Files As Object, File As Object, i As Integer
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NomDossier = ChoisirDossier
    If NomDossier = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set Dossier = fso.getfolder(NomDossier)
    Set Files = Dossier.Files

        If Files.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each File In Files
                 Workbooks.Open Filename:=File


            For Each feuille In Worksheets
              If feuille.Name Like ("*TCD RETARD*") Then

            feuille.Activate
            Range("D14").Select


        ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
     Sheets(2).ListObjects(1)

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close



End If
Next
Next
End If


End Sub
Function ChoisirDossier()
Dim objShell, objFolder, chemin, SecuriteSlash
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = _
objShell.BrowseForFolder(&H0&, "Choisisser un répertoire", &H1&)
On Error Resume Next
chemin = objFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objFolder.Title).Path & ""
If objFolder.Title = "Bureau" Then
chemin = "C:WindowsBureau"
End If
If objFolder.Title = "" Then
chemin = ""
End If
SecuriteSlash = InStr(objFolder.Title, ":")
If SecuriteSlash > 0 Then
chemin = Mid(objFolder.Title, SecuriteSlash - 1, 2) & ""
End If
ChoisirDossier = chemin
End Function
```

Comment: You will need to put an `IF` statement in after the `If Files.Count <> 0 Then`. Something like `If File <> "C:/../../filename.xslm" Then` and an `End If` later in the code. With your indentation the way it has come out in this post it's no surprise you can't work out where the `End if` should go. I think just stick it before the `End Sub` and you'll be fine

Comment: thanks for your answer :) i will work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment turned out more like an answer - I've added it here. You should be able to paste it in and go. I also added in some indentation, and added the variable names by the `Next` controls - I think it's easier to read that way

```
Sub macro3()
    Dim fso As Object, Dossier As Object, NomDossier, feuille As Worksheet
    Dim pvtTable As Object



    Dim Files As Object, File As Object, i As Integer
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NomDossier = ChoisirDossier
    If NomDossier = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set Dossier = fso.getfolder(NomDossier)
    Set Files = Dossier.Files

    If Files.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each File In Files
            If File <> ThisWorkbook.FullName Then
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=File

                 For Each feuille In Worksheets
                     If feuille.Name Like ("*TCD RETARD*") Then

                     feuille.Activate
                     Range("D14").Select

                     ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets(2).ListObjects(1)

                     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
                     ActiveWorkbook.Save
                     ActiveWorkbook.Close

                     End If
                Next feuille
            End If
        Next File
    End If
End Sub

Function ChoisirDossier()
    Dim objShell, objFolder, chemin, SecuriteSlash
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = _
    objShell.BrowseForFolder(&H0&, "Choisisser un répertoire", &H1&)
    On Error Resume Next
    chemin = objFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objFolder.Title).Path & ""
    If objFolder.Title = "Bureau" Then
        chemin = "C:WindowsBureau"
    End If
    If objFolder.Title = "" Then
        chemin = ""
    End If
    SecuriteSlash = InStr(objFolder.Title, ":")
    If SecuriteSlash > 0 Then
        chemin = Mid(objFolder.Title, SecuriteSlash - 1, 2) & ""
    End If
    ChoisirDossier = chemin
End Function
```

Comment: The code looks much better like this ;) but it doesnt work , i think its because if the lign you add , maybe it needs to be just after the if files.count .. ?

Comment: Good, if that solved your problem please accept and close the question by clicking the tick mark by this answer

Comment: The code looks much better like this ;) but it doesnt work , i think its because if the lign you add , maybe it needs to be just after the if files.count .. ? i mean this line                                                                  If File <> ThisWorkbook.FullName Then

Comment: i finally solved the problem by adding a "on error resume next"

Comment: There was an extra `End If` at the bottom of the first sub. I removed it so it should work without the `On Error...` now